# How can I start an IObservable on a specific time?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Assuming I use Rx, How can I create an IObservable which will fire an event every 5 seconds how can I make the observable start on a specific date ? 
How can I make it fire its events on a round date (every midnight ?)

Answer (score 3):

> How can I create an IObservable which will fire an event every 5
>   seconds

Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))

> how can I make the observable start on a specific date

You can use Timer for this:

```
// Fire at Jan 2014.
var jan2014 = new DateTimeOffset(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
Observable.Timer(jan2014);
```

> How can I make it fire its events on a round date (every midnight ?)

Timer has an overload that lets you fire it within a certain due time, then every set time span. It should look something like this:

```
// Fire at Jan 2014 at midnight, then every 24 hours after that (e.g. every midnight):
var jan2014 = new DateTimeOffset(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
Observable.Timer(jan2014, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Do you really care if it's up to five seconds later than midnight?
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
          .Where(x => DateTime.Now > new DateTime(1,2,2010));
```